# Как правильно сериализовать/десериализовать объекты классов со сложной структурой в json

Tags: java, json, gson

Скорее всего такой вопрос уже задавался, но всё, что я смог найти, немного но всё же не подходило.
Суть вопроса: мне в проекте нужно иметь возможность сохранять и читать из файла данные об объекте класса `CollectionManager` который хранит в себе `HashSet` объектов класса `Dragon` и ещё пару переменных. Собственно проблема состоит в том, что объекты класса `Dragon` тоже содержат в себе другие объекты уже классов `DragonCave` и `Coordinates`. Мне надо как-то сохранить информацию о том, что в collectionManager который я записываю/читаю лежит hashset драконов, у которых внутри ещё лежат их пещеры и их координаты.

Есть ещё один маленький подвопрос: у меня в менеджере коллекций и в самом драконе есть поля типа `java.time.LocalDate`, при попытке сериализовать их при помощи библиотеки Gson выбрасывается исключение "Unable to make field private static final long java.time.LocalDate.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @6d86b085"

Спасибо за потраченное на меня время.

код классов и парсера:
CollectionManager:

```
package Managers;

import Classes.Dragon;
import Exceptions.FieldNullException;
import Exceptions.IncorrectFieldValueException;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.StringJoiner;


public class CollectionManager {
    private long currentId = 0;
    private HashSet<Dragon> collection;
    private final LocalDate initializationDate;
    private String filePath;

    public CollectionManager(HashSet<Dragon> collection, String filePath) throws IncorrectFieldValueException, FieldNullException {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.collection = collection;
        initializationDate = getDate();
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath){
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public long getNewId(){
        return currentId++;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate(){
        return LocalDate.now();
    }

    public HashSet<Dragon> getCollection(){
        return collection;
    }

    public void addElement(Dragon element){
        collection.add(element);
    }

    public void removeElementById(Long id){
        collection.removeIf(d -> d.getId().equals(id));
    }

    public void clear(){
        collection.clear();
    }

    public LocalDate getInitializationDate() {
        return initializationDate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner("\n");
        if (collection.size() > 0) {
            collection.forEach((k) -> stringJoiner.add(k.toString()));
        } else {
            stringJoiner.add("The collection is empty");
        }
        return stringJoiner.toString();
    }
}
```

Dragon:

```
package Classes;

import Managers.CollectionManager;
import Exceptions.FieldNullException;
import Exceptions.IncorrectFieldValueException;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Dragon implements Comparable<Dragon>{
    private Long id; //Поле не может быть null, Значение поля должно быть больше 0, Значение этого поля должно быть уникальным, Значение этого поля должно генерироваться автоматически
    private String name; //Поле не может быть null, Строка не может быть пустой
    private Coordinates coordinates; //Поле не может быть null
    private java.time.LocalDate creationDate; //Поле не может быть null, Значение этого поля должно генерироваться автоматически
    private int age; //Значение поля должно быть больше 0
    private float wingspan; //Значение поля должно быть больше 0
    private Boolean speaking; //Поле не может быть null
    private Color color; //Поле не может быть null
    private DragonCave cave; //Поле не может быть null


    public Dragon(CollectionManager collectionManager, String name, Coordinates coordinates, int age,
                  float wingspan, Boolean speaking, Color color, DragonCave cave)
            throws FieldNullException, IncorrectFieldValueException {
        if (collectionManager == null) {
            throw new FieldNullException("CollectionManager");
        } else if (name == null) {
            throw new FieldNullException("name");
        } else if (coordinates == null) {
            throw new FieldNullException("coordinates");
        } else if (speaking == null) {
            throw new FieldNullException("speaking");
        } else if (color == null) {
            throw new FieldNullException("color");
        } else if (cave == null) {
            throw new FieldNullException("cave");
        }

        if (name.equals("")) {
            throw new IncorrectFieldValueException("name", name, "not null and not \"\"");
        } else if (age <= 0) {
            throw new IncorrectFieldValueException("age", String.valueOf(age), "greater than 0");
        } else if (wingspan <= 0) {
            throw new IncorrectFieldValueException("wingspan", String.valueOf(wingspan), "greater than 0");
        }

        this.id = collectionManager.getNewId();
        this.name = name;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.creationDate = collectionManager.getDate();
        this.age = age;
        this.wingspan = wingspan;
        this.speaking = speaking;
        this.color = color;
        this.cave = cave;
    }


    // гетеры
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public LocalDate getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public float getWingspan() {
        return wingspan;
    }

    public Boolean getSpeaking() {
        return speaking;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public DragonCave getCave() {
        return cave;
    }


    // сеттеры
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(LocalDate creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setWingspan(float wingspan) {
        this.wingspan = wingspan;
    }

    public void setSpeaking(Boolean speaking) {
        this.speaking = speaking;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setCave(DragonCave cave) {
        this.cave = cave;
    }

    public int compareTo(Dragon anotherDragon){
        if (name.compareTo(anotherDragon.getName()) != 0) {
            return name.compareTo(anotherDragon.getName());
        }
        else if (Integer.valueOf(age).compareTo(anotherDragon.getAge()) != 0){
            return Integer.valueOf(age).compareTo(anotherDragon.getAge());
        }
        else{
            return Float.valueOf(wingspan).compareTo(anotherDragon.getWingspan());
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Dragon dragon)) return false;
        return age == dragon.age && Float.compare(dragon.wingspan, wingspan) == 0 && id.equals(dragon.id) &&
                name.equals(dragon.name) && coordinates.equals(dragon.coordinates) &&
                creationDate.equals(dragon.creationDate) && speaking.equals(dragon.speaking) &&
                color == dragon.color && cave.equals(dragon.cave);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, coordinates, creationDate, age, wingspan, speaking, color, cave);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Dragon{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", coordinates=" + coordinates +
                ", creationDate=" + creationDate +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", wingspan=" + wingspan +
                ", speaking=" + speaking +
                ", color=" + color +
                ", cave=" + cave +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Coordinates:

```
package Classes;

import Exceptions.IncorrectFieldValueException;

public class Coordinates {
    private long x; //Значение поля должно быть больше -846
    private double y;

    public Coordinates(long x, double y) throws IncorrectFieldValueException{
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public long getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(long x) throws IncorrectFieldValueException {
        if (x < -845) throw new IncorrectFieldValueException("x", String.valueOf(x), "greater than -846");
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coordinates{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }
}
```

DragonCave:

```
package Classes;

import java.util.Objects;

public class DragonCave {
    private int depth;

    public DragonCave(int depth){
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof DragonCave)) return false;
        DragonCave that = (DragonCave) o;
        return depth == that.depth;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(depth);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "DragonCave{" +
                "depth=" + depth +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Color:

```
package Classes;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public enum Color {

    BLUE("синий"),
    YELLOW("жёлтый"),
    WHITE("белый");

    private final String colorName;

    private Color(String colorName) {
        this.colorName = colorName;
    }

    private final static Map<String, Color> colors = Arrays.stream(Color.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k.colorName, v->v));

    public static Color getColorByName(String colorName) {
        return colors.get(colorName);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return colorName;
    }
}
```

Parser:

```
package Managers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

import Exceptions.FieldNullException;
import Exceptions.IncorrectFieldValueException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Parser {
    private Parser() {
    }

    public static CollectionManager convertToJavaObject(File file) throws FieldNullException, IncorrectFieldValueException, FileNotFoundException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        // магическим образом получить строку(data) из всего этого
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String data = scan.nextLine();
        // это просто отвратительно, но другого способа не придумал
        CollectionManager collectionManager = gson.fromJson(data, CollectionManager.class);
        collectionManager.setFilePath(file.getPath());
        return new CollectionManager(new HashSet<>(), "");
    }

    public static void convertToJSON(CollectionManager data){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(data);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробовали реалиовать интерфейс [Serializable](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization)? По Gson не подскажу, т.к. не сталкивался, а если Jackson, то [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial), [Jackson Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations), [Mapping Nested Values with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values) и [Guide to @JsonFormat in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat).

Comment: Посмотрите этот tools [jsonschema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) с его помощью можно сгенерить POJO классы из JSON, а потом, как советовали выше, Jackson ObjectMapper или что-то аналогичное из Gson - там тоже должно быть такое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение я смог найти сам. В этом мне помогла [вот эта статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/). Пришлось написать отдельные сериализаторы и десириализаторы для каждого сложного объекта. Привожу их код (наверняка не солидный и переусложнённый, но точно работающий).

**CaveSerializer**

```
import Classes.DragonCave;
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class CaveSerializer implements JsonSerializer<DragonCave>
{
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(DragonCave cave, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        result.addProperty("depth", cave.getDepth());
        return result;
    }
}
```

**CaveDeserializer**

```
import Classes.DragonCave;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class CaveDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<DragonCave> {
    public DragonCave deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        return new DragonCave(jsonObject.get("depth").getAsInt());
    }
}
```

**CoordinatesSerializer**

```
import Classes.Coordinates;
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class CoordinatesSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Coordinates>
{
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Coordinates cords, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

        result.addProperty("x", cords.getX());
        result.addProperty("y", cords.getY());

        return result;

    }
}
```

**CoordinatesDeserializer**

```
package JSONstaff;

import Classes.Coordinates;
import Exceptions.IncorrectFieldValueException;
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class CoordinatesDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Coordinates> {
    public Coordinates deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        try {
            return new Coordinates(jsonObject.get("x").getAsLong(), jsonObject.get("y").getAsDouble());
        } catch (IncorrectFieldValueException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**DragonSerializer**

```
package JSONstaff;

import Classes.Dragon;

import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class DragonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Dragon>
{
    public JsonElement serialize(Dragon src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

        result.addProperty("id", src.getId());
        result.addProperty("name", src.getName());
        result.add("coordinates", context.serialize(src.getCoordinates()));
        result.addProperty("creationDate", src.getCreationDate().toString());
        result.addProperty("age", src.getAge());
        result.addProperty("wingspan", src.getWingspan());
        result.addProperty("speaking", src.getSpeaking());
        result.addProperty("color", src.getColor().toString());
        result.add("cave", context.serialize(src.getCave()));

        return result;
    }
}
```

**DragonDeserializer**

```
package JSONstaff;

import Classes.Color;
import Classes.Coordinates;
import Classes.Dragon;
import Classes.DragonCave;
import Exceptions.FieldNullException;
import Exceptions.IncorrectFieldValueException;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class DragonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Dragon> {
    public Dragon deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context){
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Dragon dragon = null;
        try {
            dragon = new Dragon(jsonObject.get("name").getAsString(),
                    context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("coordinates"), Coordinates.class),
                    jsonObject.get("age").getAsInt(),
                    jsonObject.get("wingspan").getAsFloat(),
                    jsonObject.get("speaking").getAsBoolean(),
                    Color.getColorByName(jsonObject.get("color").getAsString()),
                    context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("cave"), DragonCave.class));
        } catch (FieldNullException | IncorrectFieldValueException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert dragon != null;
        dragon.setId(jsonObject.get("id").getAsLong());
        return dragon;
    }
}
```

**CollectionSerializer**

```
package JSONstaff;

import Classes.Dragon;
import Managers.CollectionManager;
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class CollectionSerializer implements JsonSerializer<CollectionManager> {
    public JsonElement serialize(CollectionManager collectionManager, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context){
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray col = new JsonArray();

        for(Dragon dragon : collectionManager.getCollection()) {
            col.add(context.serialize(dragon));
        }
        result.addProperty("currentId", collectionManager.getId());
        result.add("collection", col);
        //result.addProperty("filePath", collectionManager.getFilePath());
        //не думаю, что файл должен хранить в себе путь к себе же
        result.addProperty("initializationDate", collectionManager.getInitializationDate().toString());
        return result;
    }
}
```

**CollectionDeserializer**

```
package JSONstaff;

import Classes.Dragon;
import Exceptions.FieldNullException;
import Exceptions.IncorrectFieldValueException;
import Managers.CollectionManager;
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CollectionDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CollectionManager> {
    public CollectionManager deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        HashSet<Dragon> collection = new HashSet();
        for(JsonElement dragon : jsonObject.get("collection").getAsJsonArray()) {
            collection.add(context.deserialize(dragon, Dragon.class));
        }
        try {
            return new CollectionManager(collection, jsonObject.get("filePath").getAsString());
        } catch (IncorrectFieldValueException | FieldNullException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Переделанный Parser**

```
package Managers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

import Classes.Coordinates;
import Classes.Dragon;
import Classes.DragonCave;
import JSONstaff.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Parser {
    private Parser() {
    }

    public static CollectionManager convertToJavaObject(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        StringJoiner data = new StringJoiner("");
        while (scan.hasNextLine()){
            data.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(CollectionManager.class, new CollectionDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Dragon.class, new DragonDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Coordinates.class, new CoordinatesDeserializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(DragonCave.class, new CaveDeserializer())
                .create();
        return gson.fromJson(data.toString(), CollectionManager.class);
    }

    public static void convertToJSON(CollectionManager data){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapter(CollectionManager.class, new CollectionSerializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Dragon.class, new DragonSerializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(Coordinates.class, new CoordinatesSerializer())
                .registerTypeAdapter(DragonCave.class, new CaveSerializer())
                .create();
    }
}
```